# helper method not printing anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a helper method in view like this:

```
@helper DisputeOpenedDays(DateTime createdDate)
    {

        TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(createdDate);
        string.Format("0", difference.Days);
}
```

and when I use it in view like this

```
@DisputeOpenedDays(myobj.CreatedAt)
```

It doesnt print any thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
string.Format("{0}", difference.Days);
```

The curly braces are missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@helper DisputeOpenedDays(DateTime createdDate)
{
 TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(createdDate);
 @string.Format("{0}", difference.Days);
}
```

[ASP.NET MVC 3 and the @helper syntax within Razor - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)